# MongoDB community and trigger

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

With the very last version of mongoDB community (6.01) is it possible to create something similar to "trigger" on each insert/update/delete of documents?

Comment: look at changeStreams: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/

Comment: thanks @dododo but I don't really understand how changeStreams work. How for exemple changeStream can help me to forbid to add a document if this document contain incorrect data ?

Comment: it can't do it, it just notify you about events you've been subscribed on. `to forbid to add a document if this document contain incorrect data` - I doubt that it's possible. I know that Atlas (only) supports triggers but I didn't use it so not sure whether it will be possible there

Comment: @dododo I can't understand why mogodb atlas can do it but not classic mondodb :( and can't understand why this feature is still not available in mogodb :(

Comment: you can investigate it :) As far as I know because this logic is not part of mongod/mongos binaries